# Angular + ng-bootstrap - Modal : window does not open

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm new with Angular, and i have a problem while trying the simple example with ng-bootstrap modal. 
I just tried to have a window open and instead it appears in my application.
I'd like to have a new window open as it is explained in the ng-bootstrap example.

I am using:
 - Angular 4.0.0
 - Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6
 - @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap 1.0.0-alpha.22

I have in my file.html :

```html
<template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>    
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
        </div>
    </template>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)">Launch demo modal</button>

    <pre>{{closeResult}}</pre>
```

and in my file.ts :

```html
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal, NgbModalOptions, NgbModalRef, ModalDismissReasons, NgbModalModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


@Component( {
    selector: 'app-stagiaires',
    templateUrl: './stagiaires.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./stagiaires.component.css'],
} )


export class StagiairesComponent {

    closeResult: string;

    constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

    open(content) {
        this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
            this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
        }, (reason) => {
            this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
        });
    }

    private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
        if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
            return 'by pressing ESC';
        }
        else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
            return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
        }
        else {
            return `with: ${reason}`;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have any error showing, it just open the modal in my app instead of a new window and i really don't understand why.

Edit: 
Here is a screen of my problem :
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYFs5.png)

I have the button "launch demo modal" and when i click on it the "modal title" "one fine body..." appear underneath the button instead of in a modal

Comment: You can try withhttps://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/modals

Comment: I tried but i have errors, i think it is because of Angular 4, when i install ng2-bootstrap, i have "UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY" problems, and then i tried it, and i have erros in my app.module.ts when i import the module, it says 'Cannot find name : DropdownModule' (i was trying the testing example at : https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/bootstrap4.md)

Comment: Can you please post a plunker for the same

Comment: It is the first time i post on plunker, so i'm not sure i did the right thing... But there it is : https://plnkr.co/edit/vxZR7m4e3XLwdDuIpu30

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described in [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal) NgbModal "A service to open **modal** windows" and it has no properties to open modal window in new browser window.

I've created the same app as you:

- angular 4.1.0-beta.0
- bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6
- ng-bootstrap 1.0.0-alpha.22

And modal windows works as expected, here is content of my app

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**index.html** (I use Bootstrap CDN)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularModal</title>
  <base href="/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  closeResult: string;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return  `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
  </div>
</template>

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)">Launch demo modal</button>

<hr>

<pre>{{closeResult}}</pre>
```

Comment: Sorry, i don't speak english fluently, i did not explain myself very well...
I don't even have a modal opening, it shows in the application, i edited my question with a screen of the problem.

Comment: I've edited my answer and added working example.
Haven't you forgotten to append botstrap css to your app? In this case modal windows just appear in bottom of document as you've described

Comment: Yes, that was the problem... Stupid me !
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

//1. The modal component has to be registered in entryComponents (angualr 8 and prev)

```js
//1. The modal component has to be registered in entryComponents (angualr 8 and prev)

 entryComponents: [
    YourModalComponent
  ],
  providers: [
   ...]

//2. also the model directly inputted in the open:
  openConfirmUpdateModal() {
 this.modalService.open( YourModalComponent);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had problem when i was using the https://github.com/ankosoftware/ng2-bootstrap-modal#readme so i fixed the problem to angular 8

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngm-bootstrap-modal

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.