# Modal doesn't appear correctly angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using ng-bootstrap [Here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) try to do a modal sample ,but when i click on open modal it doesn't appear although it exists inside the DOM. [image]

my angular core version :4.0.0 , @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap :1.0.0-alpha.29, bootstrap :3.3.7

test-modal.component.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
```

test-modal.component.ts

```
import {Component,Input} from '@angular/core';

import {NgbModal,NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-modal',
  templateUrl: './test-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-modal.component.css']
})
export class TestModalComponent  {

@Input() name;

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}
}
```

the open function in app.component.ts with the constructor

```
 constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}
  open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(TestModalComponent);
  }
```

the button inside app.component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open()">Launch demo modal</button>
```

Comment: Please post the code snippets you are using, or provide a [plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue). You can read more about [how to ask a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: @0mpurdy i shared the related code, see updates.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43120139/angular-ng-bootstrap-modal-window-does-not-open) might help you - Note that it mentions: Have you forgotten to append bootstrap css to your app?

Comment: @0mpurdy thanks for replying , i added the bootstrap css in my `.angular-cli.json` file in styles section

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @BrunoLM There is no errors in the console, it appears on the dom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem might be your bootstrap version `bootstrap :3.3.7`, when I got to the homepage it says it is for Bootstrap 4 (it also says bootstrap 4 on the get started).

And testing over here in a Angular 4 + Bootstrap 4 project I got it working

[image: example]

In `package.json`

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.29",
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
```

In my module

```
imports: [
  NgbModule.forRoot(), ...
],
entryComponents: [ModalTemplateComponent],
```

In a component:

```
modal: NgbModalRef;

constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }  

async open() {
  this.modal = this.modalService.open(ModalTemplateComponent);

  const result = await this.modal.result;

  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: PERFECT that's it :D