# Angular + ng bootstrap modal not appearing

Tags: css, angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using ng bootstrap in my project. All I am stuck with doing is opening a modal. I read a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43120139/angular-ng-bootstrap-modal-window-does-not-open#) but there, bootstrap css was not included.

I am following [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/PgflcPiegeec7sMx27VI?p=preview) example.

When I click the button to open the modal, modal gets appended in the DOM (visible when inspected using dev tool) but it is not visible on the screen.

I have included bootstrap css in my .angular-cli.json as

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
```

Bootstrap css is also visible in styles.bundle.js when page source is viewed.

Edit 1:
When inspected, for ngb-modal-window opacity was set to 0. When I set it to 1, popup became visible. But position of the popup is not center. It is pulled to the top. Please refer the image:

[image: ng bootstrap modal pulled to the top]

Comment: i think, json cant read `"../"`

Comment: Bootstrap is visible in styles.bundle.js, which means, json has read it.

Comment: I don't think this is related to your problem, but you might want to consider changing the order you import your styles. (styles.css after bootstrap.) The reason being that your files are compiled and served in the order that you list in your angular-cli file. So if you were to provide your own style for a bootstrap class you will find that bootstrap.min.css is overriding the style specified in styles.css.

Answer (score 1):

you can include in css

```
@import url('../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
in 'styles.css'
```

in some cases ngx-bootstrap not works exactly as expected in angular 2/4.

Comment: Tried importing bootstrap.min.css. No luck!

Comment: have you look into folder that css available?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue when try to use ng-bootstrap with bootstrap 3. install [ng-bootstrap-to-bootstrap-3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-bootstrap-to-bootstrap-3) and follow the instructions saved my day.